# Fastest function that returns true if a portion of str1 characters can be rearranged to match str2, otherwise returns false

Tags: javascript

For example:

```
function scramble(str1, str2) {
  for (var i = 0; i < str2.length; i++) {
    var letter = str1.indexOf(str2[i]);
    if (letter !== -1) {
      str1 =  str1.substring(0, letter) + str1.substring(letter + 1);
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
} 
scramble('rkqodlw', 'world') ==> True
```

But it still to slow. How can i modify this function?

Comment: Sorting the two strings should allow you to optimize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could sort the chracters of the strings and look for character of the wanted string.

```js
function scramble(left, right) {
    const a = [...left].sort();
    var i = 0;
    return [...right]
        .sort()
        .every(c => i = a.indexOf(c, i) + 1);
}

console.log(scramble('rkqodlw', 'world'));
console.log(scramble('rkqodlw', 'foo'));
```

Comment: Could you use a proper `const a = …; let i = …;` variable declaration instead of this confusing IIFE?